# PHP analogue for JAVA TripleDES function

Tags: java, php

I have a sample Java function and would like to make an analogue for PHP:

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
    {
        byte[] byteKey = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(key);


        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

        // Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream 
        // and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
        CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream,
            new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(byteKey, byteKey),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        // Convert the passed string to a byte array.
        byte[] toEncrypt = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(plainText);

        // Write the byte array to the crypto stream and flush it.
        cStream.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
        cStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        // Get an array of bytes from the 
        // MemoryStream that holds the 
        // encrypted data.
        byte[] ret = mStream.ToArray();

        // Close the streams.
        cStream.Close();
        mStream.Close();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ret);
    }
```

Here is my PHP function, but it doesn't give me the exact result:

```
function Encrypt($data, $secret)
{    
  //Generate a key from a hash
  $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

  //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
  $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

  //Pad for PKCS7
  $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
  $len = strlen($data);
  $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
  $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

  //Encrypt data
  $encData = mcrypt_encrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

  return base64_encode($encData);

}
```

The string I'm trying to encrypt is:

Java generated string: i00KAKI7U0L7fyvrEnDdB7DtaJNO1HuwRh0/J5aWnCQ= 
PHP generated string: 6065L3jC5Oji8NAVzipA4OZZ102j1zFd/KfLgAdnRX0=

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that you posted Java code? It really seems to be .NET C# code...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that are not using the cipher in the same way.
In your Java code, you are using an [IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) for your encryption, while you are not doing the same in your PHP code.
That is because [ECB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29), the mode you have specified in your PHP code, doesn't need any initialization, while whatever mode you are using in Java does.

What library are you using?
As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here in the reference of Microsoft libraries that look [very similar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the one you used with Java, the default encryption mode is 
[CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) (which is generally considered more secure than ECB). It is very likely that CBC is being used in your library too.

You need to use the same mode of encryption if you want the same result. So, either set CBC (and the same IV you used in Java) in your PHP code, or use `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` to set the ECB mode in Java.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to run the function in CBC mode, but as along as IV uses random source (MCRYPT_RAND) generated string is always different. Is there a way to define the IV that this Java sample uses?

Comment: You should have a look at the [reference](http://it1.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) for the functions that you used.
[It is evident](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you used your key as the IV as well in the first piece of code, so do the same in PHP.

Comment: Also, the part where you take the first 8 bytes of the key and add them at the end is questionable. Do you really want to do that? Since you do only in your PHP code, naturally you will get different results.
It seems to me that you need a better understanding of what your code should do, and modify samples that you got from the Internet accordingly.